# NSDateFormatter & NSDate dateFromString outputs null

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

```
NSString *dateString = [[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];
NSLog(@"DATE: %@",dateString);
// outputs 16/10 23:59:49

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat;
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"DATE: %@", date);
// outputs null
```

but it outputs null every time.
please can you help me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Init the formatter, NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to create `NSDateFormatter`:

You should replace line:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat;
```

With:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create

> NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

Answer (score 0):

You have to set year otherwise date will be shown null. You can use current year and separated your string into months and days then set like this `"dd-MM-yyyy"` or any another way which you want.

```
 NSString *string = @"16/10 23:59:49";
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSArray *arrayDateData = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
     NSString *dayStr =[arrayDateData objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *string1 =[arrayDateData objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *monStr = [[string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *timeString;
    timeString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%@-%@",2012,monStr,dayStr];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString=[df dateFromString:timeString];
    NSLog(@"date from string: %@",dateFromString);
```

I think it will be helpful to you.